# How to write a text before saving a data frame?

Tags: r

So I want to insert a text before saving my data frame. For example I used following:

```
    txt<-("The following data is the sum of PRCP, Snow and EvTr
            Date                SumPRCP")
    writeLines(txt, "Maille6412.txt")
```

Than I used following code to save data frame.

```
 write.table(Maille,file="Maille6412.txt", sep=" ", quote = F,col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

These two lines are overwriting each other can someone tell me the method of writing the lines before a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `append = TRUE` within `write.table`

```
write.table(Maille,file="Maille6412.txt", sep=" ", quote = F,col.names = F, row.names = F,append = TRUE)
```